# Security Role Names with Hyphen/Dash

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee

I just found something strange in a legacy application. There are security roles defined with a hyphen in the name:

```
App-users
App-administrators
App-superUsers
```

I am doing some testing to make sure users are seeing the correct data based on their roles, but in the code I see the `request.isUserInRole()` calls are not being passed the full role name, but instead the text after the hyphen:

```
request.isUserInRole("superUsers");
```

I expected that the calls to check the role would return false, but they return true. Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: This question is best fit to be in [security.stackexchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I disagree. I'm asking about a Java-ee specific feature and this forum has a much wider audience of Java-ee developers.

Comment: @VikasV I'm not 100% sure this question would be a better fit in security.stackexchange. That one seems to be more focussed on more general security issues, while this is a very specific Java EE API, possibly even a bug in the implementation used.

Comment: Which application server is used? Is there any custom (JASPIC) auth module or proprietary login module used? Where are the security roles that you listed defined?

Comment: JBoss AS 7.1 is the server being used. The roles are defined in an LDAP directory. If I debug the request I can see the roles listed with the principal with the full name. I can't find anything documented in the JavaEE specs that mention being able to use a short name for roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer. Apparently, there are security-role-ref entries being used to create short names for the actual roles.

Comment: Is this something specific to your application?  If not, could you link to any docs that led you to the answer?

Comment: It was specific to my app, but security role references are explained here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncba.html#bncbb